# Which API can I use to add my own logs to QEMU for debugging purpose

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I tried to add my own logs to qemu by using `fprintf(stdout, "my own log")` and `qemu_log("my own log")`, and then compiled the qemu from source code and started a VM by the following command:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -D /home/VM1-qemu-log.txt \
    -d cpu_reset \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 4096 \
    -nic user,model=virtio \
    -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/VM1.qcow2,media=disk,if=virtio \
    -nographic
```

There are CPU-related logs in `VM1-qemu-log.txt`, however, I cannot find where "my own log" is. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`qemu_log("my own log")` works, I added it to the wrong place(i.e., beginning of the 'main()' in 'qemu/vl.c', where the logging has not been setup yet). By adding it to another place(e.g. in `virtio_blk_get_request()` under `qemu/hw/block/virtio-blk.c`), I will be able to see "my own log" in `/home/VM1-qemu-log.txt`. The VM is created by:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -D /home/VM1-qemu-log.txt \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 4096 \
    -nic user,model=virtio \
    -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/VM1.qcow2,media=disk,if=virtio \
    -nographic
```